# Python combine single string element with multiple string elements

Tags: python-3.x

I have two lists:

- This one has two elements with strings with delamination ';'.

```
new_lst = [
    '50% Polyester;50% Polyester;50% Polyester;50% Polioster;50% Poliestere',
    '50% Elastane;50% Elasthanne;50% Elasthan;50% Elastano;50% Elastan'
]
```

- The Second list only has one element with same deliminator ';'

```
newSpecialComp = [
    'Back:;Dos:;Rockseite:;Parte trasera:;Schiena:'
]
```

I need to combine the FIRST element from the first list `new_lst` with the first element of the second list `newSpecialComp`.

Desired output to be a list with two elements but first being the combination of the two above.:

```
Final_lst = [
    'Back: 50% Polyester;Dos: 50% Polyester;Rockseite: 50% Polyester;Parte trasera: 50% Polioster;Schiena: 50% Poliestere',
    '50% Elastane;50% Elasthanne;50% Elasthan;50% Elastano;50% Elastan'
]
```

```
for i, j in zip(newsetSpecialComp, new_lst):
        elem2 = ';'.join(map(lambda x:i+' '+x,j.split(';')))
        final_lst.append(elem2)
        print('Final_lst :', final_lst)
```

This is what i tried. The output is close but not ideal:

```
Final_lst = [
    'Back: 50% Polyester;Back: 50% Polyester;Back: 50% Polyester;Back: 50% Polioster;Back: 50% Poliestere', 
    'Dos: 50% Elastane;Dos: 50% Elasthanne;Dos: 50% Elasthan;Dos: 50% Elastano;Dos: 50% Elastan'
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the notation you are missing to help you solve this is [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
new_lst = [
    '50% Polyester;50% Polyester;50% Polyester;50% Polioster;50% Poliestere',
    '50% Elastane;50% Elasthanne;50% Elasthan;50% Elastano;50% Elastan'
]
newSpecialComp = [
    'Back:;Dos:;Rockseite:;Parte trasera:;Schiena:'
]

finalList = new_lst.copy()

# Assuming len(newSpecialComp) <= len(new_lst)
for index, val in enumerate(newSpecialComp):
    finalList[index] = ';'.join(' '.join(x) for x in zip(val.split(';'), new_lst[index].split(';')))

print(*finalList, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
Back: 50% Polyester;Dos: 50% Polyester;Rockseite: 50% Polyester;Parte trasera: 50% Polioster;Schiena: 50% Poliestere
50% Elastane;50% Elasthanne;50% Elasthan;50% Elastano;50% Elastan
```

--- The more Verbose way to write it ---

```
new_lst = [
    '50% Polyester;50% Polyester;50% Polyester;50% Polioster;50% Poliestere',
    '50% Elastane;50% Elasthanne;50% Elasthan;50% Elastano;50% Elastan'
]
newSpecialComp = [
    'Back:;Dos:;Rockseite:;Parte trasera:;Schiena:'
]

finalList = new_lst.copy()

# Assuming len(newSpecialComp) <= len(new_lst)
for index, val in enumerate(newSpecialComp):
    str1 = val.split(';')
    str2 = new_lst[index].split(';')
    combined_strings = [' '.join(x) for x in zip(str1, str2)]
    finalList[index] = ';'.join(combined_strings)

print(*finalList, sep='\n')
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works. Could you give a brief explanation of what is happening your code?

Comment: Add `print`s to `str1`, `str2`, and `combined_strings` in the bottom code block. I could explain it but it would be shorter and probably better if you look at the values as the code runs. If you still don't understand it let me know.